# What does GEOSGeometry exactly

Tags: python, django, geodjango

Sorry it may be absurde but I got confused. I have seen two ways of creating a Polygon.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry, LineString, Polygon
1- geometry = GEOSGeometry(Polygon(coordinates, srid=4326))
2- geometry = Polygon(coordinates, srid=4326)
```

Why is it important to add GEOSGeometry instead of just using the 2) ?

Comment: I'm not sure you need the GEOSGeometry call at all. Polygon is already a subclass of GEOSGeometry.

Comment: ```GEOSGeometry``` is a lower level tool. It allows you to tap in the GEOS engine which powers geometry calculation and geometry data. So? You can handle WKT-B instead of the typical coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that GEOSGeometry() can format text and JSON (etc. compatible formats) in to spesific objects, like Point(), or Polygon().

So you don't need to use GEOSGeometry(), if you can do without.
These two definitions are equal (as far I understand). [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#automatic-spatial-transformations)

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry, Point
pnt = Point(954158.1, 4215137.1, srid=32140)
pnt = GEOSGeometry('SRID=32140;POINT(954158.1 4215137.1)')
```